# Multithreading on Class object

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am getting unhandled exception and access violation reading location error. But sometimes it is executing perfectly. Am i passing vector and vector iterators properly? What might be the possible cause of error.

```
struct DataStructure
{
    MapSmoother *m1;
    std::vector<Vertex *> v1;
    std::vector<Vertex *>::iterator vit_f;
    std::vector<Vertex *>::iterator vit_e;
    DataStructure() {
        m1 = NULL;
        v1;
        vit_f;
        vit_e;
    }
};
DWORD WINAPI thread_fun(void* p)
{
        DataStructure *input = (DataStructure*)p;
        while ( input->vit_f != input->vit_e ) {
            Vertex *v = *((input->vit_f)++);
            (*(input->m1)).relax(v);
        }
        return 0;
}
int main()
{
    //Read and encode color to Mesh
    // msmoother is an object
    DataStructure* input = new DataStructure();
    input->m1 = &msmoother;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        for(int color = 1; color <= k; color++) {
            std::vector<Vertex *> verList;
          //all the vertices with the same color index will be stored in verList vector
            input->v1 = verList;    //Copied to structure
            std::vector<Vertex *>::iterator vit1 = verList.begin();
            std::vector<Vertex *>::iterator vit2 = verList.end();
            input->vit_f = vit1;
            input->vit_e = vit2;
            HANDLE hThread[50];
            cout << "     Processing for color: " << color << endl;
            for(int j = 0; j < 50; ++j){
                hThread[j] = CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&thread_fun,input,0,NULL);
            }
            WaitForMultipleObjects(THREAD_COUNT,hThread,TRUE,INFINITE);
            //clear verList vector
            //Close Handles to all threads
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: You define an array of `HANDLE` with `THREAD_COUNT` elements but in your loop you use 50. Where is `THREAD_COUNT` defined? Is it more or less than 50 (or equal)?

Comment: @dreamlax.. it is 50.. BTW i didn't include the global variable part. Anyways THREAD_COUNT is 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not passing them in correctly.

This code:

```
input->v1 = verList;    //Copied to structure
```

Makes a copy of the vector, which is intentional by the looks of it. Since the vector contains mere pointers to actual data, you're just making a copy of a bunch of pointers. However, the followup code:

```
std::vector<Vertex *>::iterator vit1 = verList.begin();
std::vector<Vertex *>::iterator vit2 = verList.end();
input->vit_f = vit1;
input->vit_e = vit2;
```

is where the problem lays. The iterators you're setting in your `input` object are, in fact, from the local `verList`; *not* from your `input->v1` list.

Try:

```
input->vit_f = input->v1.begin();
input->vit_e = input->v1.end();
```

**Addendum**

Updated for OP to avoid race condition and uneeded vector copy.

First, redefine `DataStructure` as:

```
struct DataStructure
{
    MapSmoother *m1;
    std::vector<Vertex *>::iterator first, last
    DataStructure() : m1(NULL) {}
};
```

Next, define your thread function as:

```
DWORD WINAPI thread_fun(void* p)
{
    DataStructure *input = static_cast<DataStructure*>(p);
    if (input && input->m1)
    {
        for (std::vector<Vertex *>::iterator it = input->first
             it != input->last; ++it) 
        {
             input->m1->relax(*it);
        }
    }
    delete input;
    return 0;
}
```

And finally, invoke this as: (inside your loops)

```
// all the vertices with the same color index will be stored in verList vector
std::vector<Vertex *> verList;
// ... store vector data ...

cout << "     Processing for color: " << color << endl;
HANDLE hThread[50] = {NULL};
for(int j = 0; j < _countof(hThread); ++j)
{
    DataStructure *input= new DataStructure;
    input->first = verList.begin();
    input->last = verList.end();
    input->m1 = &msmoother
    hThread[j] = CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&thread_fun,input,0,NULL);
}
WaitForMultipleObjects(THREAD_COUNT,hThread,TRUE,INFINITE);
```

Or something like that. I just hammered this online so I've no idea if it even compiles, but should hopefully give a decent enough idea to you. Every thread gets its own pair of iterators into the `verList` array, and as such concurrent access. **note:** they cannot modify the vector; only use it. The structure they get the iterators in is allocated by the creator-thread, but owned by the thread itself, which is ultimately responsible for destroying it.

Comment: @WhozCraig.. Thank you.. it worked well.. Can you please explain this: input->v1 = verList; Instead of copying, how can i pass vector to thread function?

Comment: For this specific task, honestly I would pass a structure with two iterators only. Are you wanting to partition the data? it will change how I ammend the answer, is why I ask. Regarding `input->v1 = verList`, you're making a *copy* of the vector containing all your item pointers. Each vector's iterators are only valid for the vector they come from; none others. This was the root of your error.

Comment: @WhozCraig.. i am not partitioning data.. But if i don't use input->v1 for iterators, then the program might throw exception again(as per my understanding from prev discussion)

Comment: Iterators almost always can be *copied*. So you could just pass two iterators, then make copies of them in the thread proc, and use those instead of the passed-in ones in the struct. I can update the answer to demonstrate this if you want.

Comment: Now that I look at it, you actually have more problem than you may think. You're passing the same data structure to each thread (`input`), but modifying its content between each thread call. This is effectively a race condition, and a nasty one at that. I'll try and account for that as well. But save me some time. Is the `verList` always populated *per thread* ? If so, then you don't need two iterators, you just need a vector and your `m1` member.

Comment: I suspected that, so I made sure all 50 threads use the same physical vector. If they are required to modify it (and I can't see how they would, since you were throwing away any such mods in the old code), then copies will be needed, but I don't think so in your case.

Comment: My requirement is each thread should take different vertex and object.relax(v) should perform in parallel. All the vertices for one color should perform relax operation in parallel. But in your suggested code, each thread is taking the same iterator. And i think there is no need to pass and delete "input" each time.. I think there will be no race condition because each thread takes different vertex. Am i right?

Comment: The code passes each thread their *own* iterators. your threads cannot use the *same* iterator at the *same* time. Iterators are not thread safe by their nature, and if you're code even hints at the appearance that they are, I assure you it is blind luck. If you want to take a single sequence, and have a pool of threads iterate over it concurrently sharing single common iterator (iow no thread processes a Vertex that any other thread processes in the sequence), then you need synchronization guards, or better still, *partition* the data and each thread hits one part.

Comment: input->first = verList.begin();
input->last = verList.end(); Each time, doesn't verList.begin() point to the same iterator? We are not changing verList for a color

Comment: @WhozCraig.. Please check the code that i posted in your comment(code) at the last. Will that achieve parallelism?

Comment: @Hello sorry was away for a bit. Yes, they do, but they a *copies* (and thus independent) iterators once we put them into their own `DataSructure`. Iterators are *copyable* (again, usually). Your original code had 50 threads using the *same iterator instance*. Think of it this way. Is is safe to have a single `char *p` pointing to `"Hello"` that 50 threads are all using to walk the same string *simultaneously*? No. What about each thread having their *own* `char *p` all initially pointing to the same `"Hello"`? *Yes*, that is fine, and even requires no locking.

Comment: @Hello As I said, if you goal is to have 50 threads *all* performing the *same* operations on the *same* data in parallel (so all `Vertex *p` in a single vector are processed **50** times, the code in the answer will do that. If you want the workload spread among 50 threads, where no `Vertex *` is processed by more than **1** thread, the code at the bottom answer will *not* do that, but could be made to *very* easily by simply adjusting what values you give each thread for is `DataStructure` members `first` and `last` from the original vector. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again.. Yes i want the workload spread among 50 threads.. But how does this achieve? In this, each thread is processing all the vertices                                    for(int j = 0; j < _countof(hThread); ++j)
{
    DataStructure *input= new DataStructure;
    input->first = verList.begin();
    input->last = verList.end();
    input->m1 = &msmoother
    hThread[j] = CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&thread_fun,input,0,NULL);
}

Comment: I don't know what the exception is. There should be none unless you're  map smoother is not thread safe, which is entirely possible. However, I will change the code *once more* to account for what you *really* wanted all along. Balancing the vertex array to be pooled by all the threads. I would not use 50 btw. I would use 8 or even 4 (no more than there are cores on the box). But that I leave to you to decide. However, it will have to wait until I arrive home this evening, as for now I am a work.

Comment: May i have your mail.. i will forward mapsmoother code so that you can understand the problem better

Comment: As I said before, it is likely because your MapSmoother is not thread-safe. There are other reasons possible (using CreateThread rather than _beginthreadex, etc.) but I think it likely that code is not thread-safe. *This* code wasn't thread-safe (and using a shared iterator, it still will not be), so I have little hope for that code. I suggest running the code under gdb and tracing down your violation, but first, *split your vector up and assign each DataStructure sent to each thread a **unique** pair of iterators. Without that, anything else is ultimately a wasted effort.

Comment: @Hello OK. I threw together a [brief sample](http://ideone.com/xyPy7T) of how you can use a pool of threads to hit up slices of a vector. This should be enough to get you going. I'm afraid I can't spend anymore time on this, but I do hope it helps you with ideas on how you can pool-process your data.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a C++ noob, so I may be wrong but I think the problem may be here:

```
std::vector<Vertex *>::iterator vit1 = verList.begin();
std::vector<Vertex *>::iterator vit2 = verList.end();
input->vit_f = vit1;
input->vit_e = vit2;
```

You are passing around iterators to `verList` rather than to the vector that has been copied to the `DataStructure`. I think what you want here is:

```
input->v1 = verList; // copy to structure
input->vit_f = input->v1.begin();
input->vit_e = input->v1.end();
```

Comment: You're not *that* noob =P. this is the fundamental problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Well, if you were to put me on a scale with noobs at one end and experienced C++ developers at the other, I would be very much on the noob end of it.

Comment: Heh. I used to think I was at one end of that scale, then I came here, and my *God* I never see a day where I'm not reminded of just how much I *don't* know, so I'm right there with ya.

Comment: @dreamlax.. do you have idea on this? input->v1 = verList; Instead of copying, how can i pass vector to thread function?

Comment: @Hello: Rather than filling up `verList` and then copying to `input->v1`, you could just fill up `input->v1` directly.